# Adb waiting for device

Tags: adb

I am trying to install TWRP on mt LG Stylo 2 android 7.0 using adb. When i try to install it using this command

> fastboot flash recovery twrp.img

I get the messages waiting for device. Thing is when i type

> Adb device

My device shows. And i use adb to turn my SD card into internal storage. So why am i getting this error?

I enter recovery mode and hit enter fastboot but my phone just restart

Comment: Do you boot in fastboot mode? Seems not since adb devices still showing your device. Use adb reboot bootloader  then perform the operation.

Comment: @esQmo_ why not expanding that to an answer? From the question it's pretty clear you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Thats the thing. I get to recovery hit enter fastboot mode but my phone juat restart.. Forgot to add that will edit

Answer (score 4):

You're probably not booting to bootloader mode (fastboot mode) that is why no fastboot command is recognized by the device. The prompt `waiting for device` means the computer is waiting for a device connected in bootloader mode.

Try to switch to fastboot with the following:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Now check if fastboot sees your device:

```
fastboot devices
```

After that, perform all necessary action you want.

Note: You should have all drivers installed as well.

**Update :**

For LG, the command is a bit different. 
Start by allowing the bootloader to be written by enabling OEM unlock in the Developer options. Then:

```
adb reboot download
```

Unlock the bootloader

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

(This will reset your device and you'll get a line of text saying the bootloader was unlocked whenever you boot the device)

Afterwards, flash the recovery with :

```
fastboot flash recovery xxxxxxxx.img

fastboot reboot
```

Alternatively you can press both **volume down button** and **power button** to get into fastboot mode.

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply. I made a noob error and deleted the adb drivers thinking there must be corrupted or something. Now can't seem to get them back even when i reinstall them

Comment: Search for LG United Mobile drivers or LG Mobile Drivers WHQL

Comment: Hmm when i put the Fastboot oem unlock ut ran some command but my bootloader isn't unlocked ans next time i did it i got the Waiting for device again

Comment: How do you know it isn't unlocked? Waiting for a device is when there is no connection between the computer and the device. So if at first it worked ans afterwards it didn't, check hardware: usb cable, usb port, phone usb connector etc

Comment: I did still not working.. And i didn't get the message it iant unlocked.. Been searching for day sont2 think i can root it

Comment: Please follow this thread on XDA Developers : https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/recovery-twrp-v3-lg-stylo-2-plus-t3482169/